# "Sign in with LinkedIn" doesn't work on Mobile Safari

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

On Mobile Safari, the "Sign in with LinkedIn" button opens a blank page, but does nothing else. For example, if I open up the [documentation's example](http://developer.linkedinlabs.com/tutorials/jsapi_login_reg/example.html) on my iPhone, tapping the "Sign in with LinkedIn" button opens up a blank page (and occasionally switches focus back to the orignal page), but there are no obvious errors (even with the error console activated).

Should the the "Sign in" button work on Mobile Safari? And, if not, is there any way to "fake it"?

Comment: Hi David! Did you found a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Mobile SDK for iOS (https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/ios-sdk)

--

Was: You will need to use the REST API and OAuth 1/2.

Comment: I'm running in to this same problem over two years later. Is there a planned fix? I have to imagine we're not the only ones having this problem, and it's probably a fairly easy fix on your end in the SDK. I know it's possible, since the google sdk works perfectly.

Comment: Not sure why this answer is marked down, as it's correct. The JavaScript SDK page even mentions it is not compatible with iOS 5+. As noted is this similar answer, you'll need to fallback on the REST API http://stackoverflow.com/a/32211340/2012292