# Sign in with Linkedin doesn't trigger callback on iOS Safari when using the JS API

Tags: mobile-safari, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I'm using SignIn with Linkedin on a website, via the JS API. It works fine on the few desktop browsers I've tested (Chrome and FF on Windows, Safari on MacOS), and on a slightly outdated Android Chrome. But it fails on iOS Safari (I use iOS 7).

The issue is that on iOS Safari, the callback passed as argument to `IN.User.authorize` is not executed.

The line looks like this: `IN.User.authorize(this._getProfileData, this);`

`_getProfileData` is executed on the desktop browsers mentioned above and Android Chrome, but not iOS Safari.

This issue can even be reproduced without iOS: via Chrome's developer tools, in device mode for iPhones and iPads.

Any clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, LinkedIn's JS SDK is incompatible with iOS 5+ due to the way that Javascript is paused during cross-window communication processes.  You will need to fall back to server-side REST calls to ensure 100% platform compatibility.

Comment: +1 - This is a HUGE caveat and should be clearly indicated in the LinkedIn JS SDK documentation so people don't waste days of their time implementing this as a solution (like I just did) just to find out that it doesn't work on iOS. The documentation merely says that the SDK supports Safari 5+. Terrible support / documentation, LinkedIn. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Since the 1st of May 2019 this is no longer working : https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates

> Sign In with LinkedIn: Sign In with LinkedIn enables members to choose
>   a more convenient way to log-in to third party apps and allows those
>   apps to learn more about their new user. This API will only recognize
>   a new “Lite Profile” permission, which supports a reduced set of
>   member profile fields. See the documentation for more details.

and

> SDKs: Our JavaScript and Mobile Software Development Kits (SDKs) will
>   stop working. Developers will need to migrate to using OAuth 2.0
>   directly from their apps.